# Group By Multiple Columns - LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have seen examples of multiply group by columns, but for classes.  I am trying to do this for a EnumerableDataRowList. but I get "Invalid anonymous type member declarator."

```
                    EnumerableDataRowList<DataRow> enumerableRowCollection = new EnumerableDataRowList<DataRow>(reportData.Select("WeekKey <> '0'"));


                var groupedRows1 = from row in enumerableRowCollection
                                  group row by new {row["NETWORK"], row["Week"] };
```

also, I seen some people combine the columns in some case to get the same results.  Any benefit in doing it that way

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to assign an identifier to the values:

```
         var groupedRows1 = from row in enumerableRowCollection
                            group row by new { Network = row["NETWORK"], Week = row["Week"] };
```

You normally aren't required to specify an identifier if you're using a field or property reference as it'll just reuse the name of that member - but in this case you're accessing an indexer property, so there's no way to get a name from it.