# Group by column one, group by column two and then count column two on an EnumerableRowCollection

Tags: c#, linq, count, group-by

I have an EnumerableRowCollection in C# .Net, with two columns. I want to Group By the firstColumn, followed by the second column, then count the second column.

My EnumerableRowCollection is based on a DataTable that looks like this on a DataGridView:

[image: Data Grid View]

If this were a MySQL table, I would achieve what I want like so:

```
SELECT `Product Name`, 
       `Upsell Price`, 
       Count(`Upsell Price`) 
  FROM `tblWhatever` 
  GROUP BY `Product Name`, `Upsell Price`;
```

I need this equivalent in LINQ

I have constructed the DataTable programmatically like so:

```
DataTable myDataTable = new DataTabl();
DataColumn myColumn = new DataColumn("My Column");
myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataTable);
myDataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "whatever" });
myDataGridView.DataSource = myDataTable;
```

I found `Daniel Schaffer`'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061658/group-by-multiple-columns-linq), which helped me with the group by part, but I am stuck on the count as shown below:

```
var queryableData = myDataTable.AsEnumerable();
var result = from row in queryableData
          group row by new { ProductName = row["Product Name"], 
                             ProductPrice = row["Product Price"] };
```

How do I edit my LINQ query to allow me to group by column one, then group by column two and then count column two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
var result = from row in queryableData
          group row by new { ProductName = row["Product Name"], 
                             ProductPrice = row["Product Price"] } into grp
          select new { grp.Key.ProductName , 
                       grp.Key.ProductPrice, 
                       Count = grp.Count()  };
```